Prove that edge connectivity of a complete graph with $n$ vertices is $n-1$
Question
How to quickly see that the edge connectivity (minimum number edges to be removed to make a connected graph have more than one component) of a complete graph having $n$ vertices is $n-1$?
Thoughts
Showing the (vertex) connectivity of $K_{n}$ was fairly intuitive, remove any $m (m < n-1)$ vertices, then the remaining vertices will definitely have edges between them. But I am not able to think a simple argument for edge connectivity. Please help me see it.

Suppose you remove some edges and the graph is partitioned into two disconnected subgraphs with $k$ and $n - k$ vertices respectively. How many edges must you have removed (at least)? For what value of $1\leq k \leq n - 1$ is this number minimized?

So, I will have to remove $k(n-k)$ edges, and it is minimum at $k = 1$ or $k = n-1$, as see from the graph of $kn-k^{2}$. Thanks a lot. I got it.
